# Python one line if else statement SyntaxError, the error is at the "else", what can be the problem?

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
def censor_string(txt, lst, char):
    return " ".join([char*len(i) for i in txt.split() if i in lst else i])
print(censor_string("The cow jumped over the moon.", ["cow", "over"], "*"))
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to write

```
def censor_string(txt, lst, char):
    return " ".join([char*len(i) if i in lst else i for i  in txt.split() ])
print(censor_string("The cow jumped over the moon.", ["cow", "over"], "*"))
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght I downvoted because it doesn't explain what the problem is and how it solves it. *"You have to write this"* shouldn't considered to be valid explanation. And most of the time, the downvotes on the posts like this one simply does nothing because people tend to upvote if a *correct* answer is downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension syntax is this:

```
[expression for ... in iterable if something]
```

while the `if` clause being optional and used only for filtering. So you can't have an `else` there. But, you have control over the *expression*. A conditional expression is also an *expression* so you can write something like this:

```
def censor_string(txt, lst, char):
    return " ".join([char*len(i) if i in lst else i for i in txt.split()])

print(censor_string("The cow jumped over the moon.", ["cow", "over"], "*"))
```

to achieve your desired result:

```
The *** jumped **** the moon.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you can put conditionals in a list comprehension:

```
[ AA or BB for elem in sequence if elem something]
  ^^^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- use the element or not in the 
           ^--- what to put into the result           result - no ELSE allowed
```

so the correct version of yours would be

```
def censor_string(txt, lst, char):
    return " ".join([char*len(i) if i in lst else i for i in txt.split()])
print(censor_string("The cow jumped over the moon.", ["cow", "over"], "*"))
```

to get

```
The *** jumped **** the moon.
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```py
def censor_string(txt, lst, char):
    return " ".join([char*len(i) if i in lst else i for i in txt.split() ])
print(censor_string("The cow jumped over the moon.", ["cow", "over"], "*"))
```

Output

```
The *** jumped **** the moon.
```

Comment: Isn't it identical with another answer?

Comment: @OlvinRoght It seems to be. But, I had no idea about the other code till I posted my answer.